# Running rkhunter on Linux

Tags: linux, antimalware, ubuntu

Currently each time before an application and after an application is either installed or updated including regular patches, the command `rkhunter --propupd` is run, followed by the command `rkhunter --update` before the command `rkhunter --check`.

What is the recommended approach of running the command and its frequency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ossec is also capable to identify rootkit and backdoor like rkhunter. When I look at the OSSEC default configurations, i've seen following descriptions.

```
frequency
Frequency that the rootcheck is going to be executed (in seconds).

Defaults: 36000 (10 hours)

Allowed: Time (in seconds)
```

Also I believe 10 hours is OK for script execution through crontab.